# show picture in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show picture in grid view but I have got a lot of problems. I downloade code [from there](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1551/how-to-retrieve-saved-images-from-sql-server-database-and-show-on-the)
and I want to change it for use my problem, but I have got truble with exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

from there:

```
string _connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Check your connection string in web.config

Comment: <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorksLT2012_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: Change `<add name="ConnectionString" ...` to `<add name="ConnStr" ...

Comment: i make select from query builder but this select statemant i want use in my code. But i have troubles with filter (i have a lot of gridviews) And there is

Comment: SELECT SalesLT.Product.ProductNumber, SalesLT.Product.Name, SalesLT.Product.Size, SalesLT.Product.Color, SalesLT.Product.ListPrice, SalesLT.ProductModel.ProductModelID, SalesLT.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID, SalesLT.Product.ProductID, SalesLT.Product.ThumbNailPhoto FROM SalesLT.Product INNER JOIN SalesLT.ProductCategory ON SalesLT.Product.ProductCategoryID = SalesLT.ProductCategory.ProductCategoryID INNER JOIN SalesLT.ProductModel ON SalesLT.Product.ProductModelID = SalesLT.ProductModel.ProductModelID WHERE (SalesLT.ProductModel.ProductModelID = @filter3)

Comment: and this is eror Must declare the scalar variable "@filter3".

Comment: Hard to guess what you are trying. If this is a sqldatasource, there are some good tutorials available. See one [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479344.aspx).